# D3 + Google Map API

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to draw three points on the google map using D3 library. For each point, I have longitude and latitude values. I have the following code that works perfectly.

```
enter code here
 <!DOCTYPE html>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
  <style>

  html, body, #map {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }

  .stations, .stations svg {
     position: absolute;
   }

  .stations svg {
     width: 60px;
     height: 20px;
     padding-right: 100px;
     font: 10px sans-serif;
  }

 .stations circle {
   fill: brown;
   stroke: black;
   stroke-width: 1.5px;
  }

 .hull {
    fill: steelblue;
    stroke: steelblue;
    stroke-width: 32px;
    stroke-linejoin: round;
  }

 </style>
 <div id="map"></div>
 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
 <script>

  // Create the Google Map…
  var map = new google.maps.Map(d3.select("#map").node(), {
  zoom: 13,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(33.775268, -84.376768),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
 });

 data = {
   "KMAE":[-84.382950,33.771850],
    "KSJC":[-84.376768,33.775268],
   "KMCE":[-84.383606,33.777921]
 }

 var overlay = new google.maps.OverlayView();

 // Add the container when the overlay is added to the map.
 overlay.onAdd = function() {
   layer = d3.select(this.getPanes().overlayLayer).append("div")
    .attr("class", "stations");

// Draw each marker as a separate SVG element.
// We could use a single SVG, but what size would it have?
overlay.draw = function() {
  var projection = this.getProjection(),
      padding = 10;

  var marker = layer.selectAll("svg")
      .data(d3.entries(data))
      .each(transform) // update existing markers
      .enter().append("svg")
      .each(transform)
      .attr("class", "marker");

  // Add a circle.
  marker.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 6.5)
      .attr("cx", padding)
      .attr("cy", padding);

  function transform(d) {
    d = new google.maps.LatLng(d.value[1], d.value[0]);
    d = projection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(d);
    return d3.select(this)
        .style("left", (d.x - padding) + "px")
        .style("top", (d.y - padding) + "px");
  }

    };
  };

  // Bind our overlay to the map…
  overlay.setMap(map);

 </script>
```

This code works perfectly fine. My only challenge is that I want to add lines that connect the first point with the second point and the second point with the third one. However, I am not sure how I should be doing that. Any suggestion?

Comment: you add individual SVG's on the page and you expect to be able to draw inbetween them? Project all your points, calculate the bounding, add some margin, place an SVG of the desired size on the page and position the markers relative to the SVG position

Comment: @rioV8 Thank you so much for replying. I tried to apply the changes you mentioned and created a single SVG (http://jsfiddle.net/b17knu28/5/). However, not sure why all the points overlapping. Probably I am not positioning the svg correctly.

Comment: you are not positioning the SVG at ALL. Use bounding box of the projected points and read first comment till the end